# Finding all records that are greater than 30 minutes old in Sequelize

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

In Sequelize, how can I:

Only return entries that are at least 30 minutes old or older (as indicated by their `created_at` datetime field).

This isn't working properly (using postgreSQL).

```
where: {
  [Op.and]: [
    {
      active: true,
    },
    {
      updated_at: { // DataTypes.DATE

        // Return only if this datetime value is >= 30 minutes

        [Op.gte]: Sequelize.literal("NOW() - (INTERVAL '30 MINUTE')"), 
      },
    }
}
```

Does not seem to be working properly.

Should I be using EXTRACT or taking the diff between the `updated_at` and `new Date(updated_at) - 30`?

```
Sequelize.where(
  Sequelize.literal(`EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM TIMESTAMP '???')`),
  {
    [Op.gte]: 30,
  }
 )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first query `updated_at: { [Op.gte]: Sequelize.literal("NOW() - (INTERVAL '30 MINUTE')"),}` is specifying `updated_at >= new() - interval '30 minute'`, i.e. entries that have been updated in the last 30 minutes.

To get the old entries you should take the entries that have been modified before 30 that time, e.g. `updated_at: { [Op.lt]: Sequelize.literal("NOW() - (INTERVAL '30 MINUTE')")}`

Regarding the second attempt

[EXTRACT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT)(minute from date) will give only the minute part of the date.

Assuming that `extract(minute from updated_at){ [Op.gte]:30 }` generates
`WHERE extarct(minute from updated_at) >= 30`, this will get all the rows from where the minute component of the timestamp is greater than 30, e.g. 11:34, 15:55, etc.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the extract. Seems like it's not useful for me.So, I'm not sure if it's because this is in an `include`, or what, but trying your suggestion with the `lt`, sounds right in theory, but it's still returning rows that aren't at least 30 minutes old... Is there a way to somehow select `updated_at`, add 30 minutes, and then check to see if it's > that value in the `where` condition? Only other idea I have is to add 30 minutes to the current date and add a new column to my table and then just check that (diff of that and now minus 30 minutes) when I'm querying....

Comment: Can you include the generated query? Maybe you are using a left/right join, using [required](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/advanced-association-concepts/eager-loading/#required-eager-loading): true should make it an inner join. Also adding the where in the main query could also fix.

Comment: Thanks to you, I actually discovered what I was doing wrong. I should have added this condition to the top level (parent) entity that I'm calling `findAndCountAll` on. LOL. Thanks for the help. A very minor but stupid mistake on my part!